# unix shell script to parse logs using grep

Tags: unix, shell, xml-parsing

Contents of `events<xyz>.log`:

```
<log>  
 <time>09:00:30</time>  
 <entry1>abcd</entry1>  
 <entry2>abcd</entry2>  
 <id>john</id>  
</log>  
<log>
 <time>09:00:35</time>  
 <entry1>abcd</entry1>  
 <entry2>abcd</entry2>  
 <id>steve</id>  
</log>  
<log>  
 <time>09:00:40</time>  
 <entry1>abcd</entry1>  
 <entry2>abcd</entry2>  
 <id>john</id>  
</log>
```

I want to extract entry1 and entry2 tags of all `<log>` entries with `<id>` 'john' into a file. i want to do this in a shell script which would look in all *.log files in a directory. The output should be similar to the following.

Contents of a.out:

```
<time>09:00:30</time>   
<entry1>abcd</entry1>  
<entry2>abcd</entry2>

<time>09:00:40</time>  
<entry1>abcd</entry1>  
<entry2>abcd</entry2>
```

I am new to shell scripting, however I tried with some basic commands to at least look at the logs:

```
$ grep -B 3 -in '<id>john</id>' * > /tmp/a.out
```

above command gives me output with 3 lines above id tag for john as follows

```
...   
events111.log-100- <time>09:00:40</time>  
events111.log-101- <entry1>abcd</entry1>  
events111.log-102- <entry2>abcd</entry2>  
events111.log-103- <id>john</id>  
....  
events112.log-200- <time>06:56:03</time>  
events112.log-201- <entry1>abcd</entry1>  
events112.log-202- <entry2>abcd</entry2>  
events112.log-203- <id>john</id>
```

This is fine, but the problem is that -3 lines wont work every time, there could be more tags in between, so there is some parsing logic needed to find out the text from `<time>` to `</id>`.

I would really appreciate some help around formulating a script for this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using a `xml` grepping tool like [xml starlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) to pick out the pieces from these log files? It would be much more cleaner.

Comment: wow! xml starlet is a great tool! i am trying to use the xml sel <global-options> {<template>} [ <xml-file> ... ]
 and the -i option for conditions

Comment: It's been a long time since I've used it but I remember getting frustrated with jury rigged awk/sed/shell scripts. xml starlet was a *big* relief.

Answer (score 2):

Doing this with a shell script is not really the right tool for the job. You really need a parser. Here's one in python for a single file. You could throw a loop around this and do an entire directory of log files.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, Tag   

f = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')   
soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read())    
for log in soup.findAll('log'):
 if log.id.contents[0] == "john":
   print log.entry1
   print log.entry2
```

Comment: You forgot to mention that BeautifulSoup is not part of a standard Python installation.

Comment: If you're writing a Python script, consider `elementree` which is part of the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

```
has() { echo "$line" | grep "$1" >/dev/null; }
while read line; do
 has /log && echo;
 (has time   || has entry1 || has entry2) && echo "$line";
done;
```

prints

```
<time>09:00:30</time>
<entry1>abcd</entry1>
<entry2>abcd</entry2>

<log> <time>09:00:35</time>
<entry1>abcd</entry1>
<entry2>abcd</entry2>

<time>09:00:40</time>
<entry1>abcd</entry1>
<entry2>abcd</entry2>
```

You may or may not want to suppress that "`<log>`" in the "time" line.

Comment: But you match the unwanted "Steve".

Comment: This is going to be incredibly slow. And it won't be selective at all.   Your entire script could be replaced by the equally wrong but *much* faster: `grep 'time\|entry1\|entry2' * | sed 's|.*/log.*||`.

Answer (score 0):

For others still looking for a shell script to find specific string(s) in log(s) file(s) locally or remotely I have written this shell script:

https://github.com/ijimako/logs_extractor

Cheers,

Comment: Please take time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion. The community here tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. **However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers.**

Comment: @WaynePhipps sorry I didn't knew that. I have edited my answer.